# Reducing ABBannerView Size for getting width=300 not 320

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an issue while displying the BannerView on my screen like below image:
[image]

Even i'm setting  bannerFrame.size.width = 300; , but notgetting.

So i need to reduce the size of bannerView by 10+10= 20 pixels to avoid overlapping the bannerView on my background imageview.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> **A banner view must always use one of the standard sizes** defined in
>   “Content Size Identifiers.” This is to ensure that the advertisement
>   is drawn correctly. You configure the banner view’s
>   requiredContentSizeIdentifiers property with the set of possible sizes
>   your view is allowed to use in your application. To change the size of
>   the banner view, do not set the bounds directly; instead set the
>   currentContentSizeIdentifier property to one of the size identifiers
>   included in that set. You can retrieve the actual dimensions that a
>   particular identifier equates to on a specific device by calling the
>   sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier: class method.

**Update**

Please refer this [document for BannerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW2)

To create and give size to ADBannerView:

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

Comment: Can u please provide me some code lines to get a proper idea plz..?

Comment: i also did the same, then it is setting with 320 width, but i need banner width as 300 only. Is it possible?

Comment: first line of documentation in the answer clearly says that "A banner view must always use one of the standard sizes defined in “Content Size Identifiers.”. So not its not possible because its not taking frame from setFrame or bounds method its taking frame from the Content Size Identifiers.